# if function in python. getting an error in break statement

Tags: python-3.x

getting an error in the last if statement. show an syntax error as break is outside loop. The code is unable to break the statement when q is pressed.The code is from the github sorry for not providing the github link. ooking forward for some simple solutions. some packages have been imported like cv2, numpy and pandas

```
first_frame = None

status_list = [None, None]

times = []

df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["start", "End"])

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    check, frame = video.read()

    status = 0
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame = gray
    continue

    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, gray)
    thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    thresh_delta = cv2.dilate(thresh_delta, None, iterations=0)

    countours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
        thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in countours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1000:
        continue
        status = 1
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    status_list.append(status)

    status_list = status_list[-2:]

    if status_list[-1] == 1 and status_list[-2] == 0:
        times.append(datetime.now())
    if status_list[-1] == 0 and status_list[-2] == 1:
        times.append(datetime.now())

cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
cv2.imshow("capturing", gray)
cv2.imshow("delta", delta_frame)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh_delta)

for i in range(0, len(times), 2):
    df = df.append({"start": times[i], "End": times[i + 1]}, ignore_index=true)
    df.to_csv("Times.csv")

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # press q to quit
      break

video.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # press q to quit
break
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please edit your post to reduce the code to a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well the exact error message __and traceback__ this minimal example produces.

Comment: This being said and as the error message mentions, `break` is indeed illegal outside a loop (`while` or `for` loop). I don't know what you expect it to do here, so you may want to explain this too.

Comment: Also there are quite a few obvious issues with your current snippet,